# Смена цвета подчеркивания EditText внутри OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android

Всем привет. Мне нужно менять цвет подчеркивания **EditText** внутри `OnFocusChangeListener` в зависимости от заполненности поля. Если поле не пустое и оно не в фокусе, то должен сохраниться выбранный цвет.

Для изменения цвета подчеркивания использую такую конструкцию:

```
mBinding.phoneNumber.getBackground().setColorFilter(mRed, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Снаружи `OnFocusChangeListener` все норм работает, цвет меняется. Но внутри почему то перестает работать. При возвращении/потери фокуса я вижу цвета `EditText` по умолчанию.

Вот метод в котором все это должно работать:

```
private void changeFieldColor() {
        // Всегда красный
        mBinding.phoneCode.getBackground().setColorFilter(mRed, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        // Красный, только если поле активно/непустое
        mBinding.phoneNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (hasFocus) {
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter(mRed, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            } else {
                if (mBinding.phoneNumber.getText().length() == 0) {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Помогите понять почему внутри `OnFocusChangeListener` не работает изменение цвета? И что сделать, чтобы смена цвета заработала?

Comment: Почему во втором условии вы проверяете длину строки и ставите ей цвет по умолчанию?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, если строка пустая, то должен быть цвет по умолчанию. Если нет, то должен остаться выбранный цвет.

Comment: А вы знаете как clearColorFilter? он к цвету по умолчанию возвращает? Мне кажется вы должны setColorFilter(defaultColor) делать заместо clear.

Comment: @yno7, проблема начинается именно внутри `OnFocusChangeListener`, во всех остальных случаях все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае все работает, если запускать смену цвета через Runable.

```
private void changeFieldColor() {
        mBinding.phoneNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            v.post(() -> {
                if (!isEmpty()) {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(mDefaultColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                } else {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                }
            });
        });
    }
```